# Check uniqueness of arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of numpy arrays. Each array is a sequence of binary values, e.g. `[0,1,1,0,1,0]`. I would like to compare all the arrays in the list and obtain another list with all the indexes of the array having exactly the same sequence of numbers.

For example if `A=[[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0]]` I would like to obtain something like `B = [[1,3],[2],[4,5]]`.

I am able to verify the uniqueness or similarity of each array using a double for loop like:

```
for i in xrange(len(A)):
    for j in xrange(i+1,len(A)):
        if (A[i]==A[j]).all():
            print 'Duplicate of arrays %d and %d' %(i,j)
```

but then I do not know how to group the indexes of the arrays that are equal between them in another list, array, matrix or whatever.

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: It's not because the sum is 0 that the two are equal: consider `[0,1]` and `[1,0]`. Here the diff is `[-1,1]` which sums up to `0`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for pointing the oversight. I have edited the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use a dictionary approach:

```
dic = {}
B = []
for idx,row in enumerate(A):
    trow = tuple(row)
    if trow not in dic:
        dic[trow] = len(dic)
        B.append([idx])
    else:
        B[dic[trow]].append(idx)
```

Note that indices start here with **`0`**, if you want the indices to start at `1`, you simply can use the alter the code by feeding it to the `enumerate(..)` call:

```
dic = {}
B = []
for idx,row in enumerate(A,1):
    trow = tuple(row)
    if trow not in dic:
        dic[trow] = len(dic)
        B.append([idx])
    else:
        B[dic[trow]].append(idx)
```

which produces as `result`:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> A=[[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0]]
>>> dic = {}
>>> B = []
>>> for idx,row in enumerate(A,1):
...     trow = tuple(row)
...     if trow not in dic:
...         dic[trow] = len(dic)
...         B.append([idx])
...     else:
...         B[dic[trow]].append(idx)
... 
>>> B
[[1, 3], [2], [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.group_by(A).split(np.arange(len(A)))
```